# Potential energy of an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, potential-energy, ideal-gas

According to equipartition theorem, for ideal gas in thermal equilibrium, each vibrational mode will get $kT/2$ for kinetic energy and $kT/2$ for potential energy.

But at the same time, we assume that the potential energy of ideal gas is zero. It seems that there is a contradiction. Or if equipartition theorem does not apply to ideal gas. Shouldn't the kinetic energy be the same as total energy, which will be $kT$ instead of $kT/2$?

Answer (score 1):

Review the equipartition theorem.    It tells us that each degree of freedom quadratic in coordinate or momentum contributes $\frac{1}{2} kT$ per element.   Ideal gas particles have no internal structure, so there is no contribution from internal mechanisms.  The energy of the particle does not depend on location, so there is no dependence on coordinate, and no contribution from coordinate.  That leaves kinetic energy.  In a 3d box there are three independent momenta:   $p_x$, $p_y$, and $p_z$, so the average energy per "atom" is $\frac{3}{2}kT$.

Also, why do you think the average energy per "atom" should be $kT$?

Comment: The reason I think the average energy per "atom" should be $kT$ is that, if you consider ideal gas as an ensemble of quantum harmonic oscillator, the mean energy of one oscillator at high temperature limit will be $kT$. Then if potential energy is zero, shouldn't all of that energy be kinetic energy? Source: https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s12/lecture-notes/chapter06.pdf  (Page 24-25)

Comment: @SpencerYD I may be missing something, but in what possible sense could you consider a monatomic ideal gas to be like an ensemble of harmonic oscillators? Are you perhaps referring to a diatomic gas, whose constituents have vibrational degrees of freedom and “internal” potential energy corresponding to bonds, but no intermolecular potential energy?

Comment: @J.Murray I think you have a point here. My professor deduced the energy of a monatomic ideal gas from harmonic oscillators in class and I am pretty sure he mentioned that the total energy would just be the kinetic energy in this case. But now that I think about it, it may not be appropriate to apply the oscillator model to an ideal gas.